# O try-catch-resources do Java faz o flush automaticamente?

Tags: java

Quando se usa um objeto do tipo `FileInputStream` e `FileOutputStream` dentro de um **try-catch-resources** o java automaticamente usa o **close()** no final, mas, e o **flush()** é automático ou não?

```
// Exemplo
try(FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("arquivo.txt")){
    try (BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos)) {
        bos.write("Teste");
        bos.flush(); // Precisa usar o flush()
    }
    fos.flush(); // Precisa usar o flush()
}
```

Comment: Sim, o flush também é automático.
Veja este exemplo: [Java try/catch/finally best practices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092914/java-try-catch-finally-best-practices-while-acquiring-closing-resources)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O flush ser ou não automatico depende da implementação da classe concreta que você usar.

O try with resources espera apenas objetos Closeable ou AutoCloseable, não está ligado diretamente ao flush, porem algumas implementações dessas interfaces executam o flush antes do close.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32324492/is-flush-call-necessary-when-using-try-with-resources